# ?format=json returns 'Not acceptable format: json'

Tags: 8

I am trying to set up the REST module for Drupal8.2.7. Install went through without problems.

I tried to follow this documentation page https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview to set up a simple resource for getting nodes.

I followed the descriptions for 'Drupal 8.2 & Later: ' and created this yml file in the this folder  \Drupal\rest\RestResourceConfigInterface

```
id: entity.node
plugin_id: 'entity:node'
granularity: method
configuration:
  GET:
    supported_formats:
      - json
    supported_auth:
      - basic_auth
      - cookie
```

Once that was done I cleared the cache and expected to be able to get node 1 as json using this url:

```
/node/1?_format=json
```

However, all I receive is: 
    {"message":"Not acceptable format: json"}

What am I missing here?

Update: 
I went to here
    /admin/config/development/configuration/single/export
and exported 
    entity.node

```
uuid: d44c745b-d69b-4893-8f31-b65d0fe80bf0
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - basic_auth
    - hal
    - node
  _core:
    default_config_hash: t_jfECmZhJqBOJuSOFn87EOi_TWi-_fRYTuJgd19vgg
  id: entity.node
    plugin_id: 'entity:node'
    granularity: resource
  configuration:
    methods:
      - GET
      - POST
      - PATCH
      - DELETE
    formats:
      - json 
      - hal_json
    authentication:
      - basic_auth
    GET:
      supported_formats:
        - json
        - xml
      supported_auth:
        - basic_auth
        - cookie
    POST:
      supported_formats:
        - hal_json
        - json
        - xml
      supported_auth:
        - basic_auth
        - cookie
   DELETE:
     supported_formats:
       - hal_json
       - json
       - xml
  supported_auth:
    - basic_auth
    - cookie
  PATCH:
    supported_formats:
      - hal_json
      - json
      - xml
    supported_auth:
      - basic_auth
      - cookie
```

However, trying to get my node via the mentioned url '/node/1?_format=json' still returns {"message":"Not acceptable format: json"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\Drupal\rest\RestResourceConfigInterface` is a namespace not a directory structure.

Configuration files need to be imported into the active configuration which is stored in the database.

In the case of a single config file:

1. Go to the
   page `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import`
2. Under "Configuration type" select "REST resource configuration" In the box
3. At "Paste your configuration here" paste your REST YAML configuration

Configuration can be exported and imported using the config directory, as specified in settings.php with the line `$config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/default/config';`.

To export the current active configuration to files in the `sync` directory use the drush command: `drush config-export`

To import configuration from files in the `sync` directory and overwrite your current active configuration, go to the page `/admin/config/development/configuration`.

Another option is to use the [REST UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/restui) module to configure your REST services.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Much appreciated.
I do not fully understand how to enable 'JSON' for 'nodes' though.
I will update the questions with my exported yml files

Comment: Just to clarify: I went to the URL you described, I exported the existing yml and made sure  that ' json' was listed as supported format for 'nodes'.

Comment: What happens when you follow the 3 step instructions I suggested to import the YAML into configuration? This will make sure it has been imported correctly.

Comment: @Uwe Exporting the configuration is just a third of the process; you still need to import it back in the configuration.

Comment: I have the same problem using the REST UI module. That was the reason for me to try it the other way in the first place

Comment: @imclean I exported the configuration file, sure enough only hal_json was allowed. I added json and imported it. The import went through without errors. The problem consists. When using 'json' as format it is supposed to be invalid, when using hal_json I get an empty result

Comment: The **serialization** module is a dependency of **REST** yet it isn't listed as one in your config export. Can you confirm it is enabled? After you've imported your preferred config, export it again to see if the config you're importing is what's being saved.

Comment: OK, your initial answer is certainly correct. I started from scratch just a moment ago and noticed another problem. Drupal was complaining about an untrusted host setting.
After fixing that problem I installed RestUI, and it worked out of the box.

I fully understand that Drupal is opensource and fantastic, but the documentation can bring a man to tears, thanks again for correct answers!